# Not grabbing all the array using fputcsv

Tags: php

I have a nested array in PHP. I want to export all of the contents to a csv. I am able to export fine. However, it is only taking all but the last array. It is getting chopped off at the end. When I put another array in, it doesn't even take that. My memory limit in the .ini is set to 128M..

Any ideas as to why I am not getting all of the contents from the array into the csv?

PHP

```
$bomArrSave = $_POST['bomArrSave'];
$fp = fopen('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testing\php\file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($bomArrSave as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Array OUTPUT FROM CSV -- Notice that chopped off part at the end... the data is the same at the row above it but it is not showing in the csv.

```
21380,1,0,0,1,1,140,36757,36757,DS5101,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,54,1,629,2102,2102,"FU5202(x3),FU5207(x3),FU5212(x3) FU5217(x3),FU5221(x3),FU5227(x3) FU5232(x3),FU5237(x3),FU5245(x3) FU5250(x3),FU5255(x3),FU5260(x3)  FU5265(x3),FU5270(x3),FU5275(x3) FU5309(x3),FU5317(x3),FU5326(x3)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,7,1,629,2134,2134,"FU5302(x3),FU5562(x2),FU5566(x2)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,10,1,629,1964,1964,"FU5117(x3),FU5555(x2), FU5573(x2),FU5577(x2),FU5550",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,6,1,629,2446,2446,"FU5123(x3),FU5129(x3)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,3,1,629,36829,36829,FU5102(x3),0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,2,1,629,2132,2132,FU5569(x2),0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,12,1,629,1378,1378,"FU5135(x3),FU5145(x3),FU5151(x3) FU5157(x3)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,2,1,629,36883,36883,"FU5608,FU5619",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,629,36895,36895,FU5622,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,2,1,629,2849,2849,FU5164(x2),0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,2,1,629,1380,1380,FU5546(x2),0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,671,25722,25722,0,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,6,1,675,36888,36888,"CR5848,CR5852,CR5856,CR5860, CR5864,CR5868",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,6,1,675,36889,36889,"(CR5848,CR5852,CR5856,CR5860, CR5864,CR5868)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,4,1,675,36924,36924,X3,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,675,36925,36925,X3,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,675,36932,36932,X1,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,4,1,675,25717,25717,"GB6001,GB6022,GB6022A,GB6044",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,8,1,675,25716,25716,"GB6001,GB6022,GB6022A,GB6044",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,82,1,675,25715,25715,"GB6001,GB6022,GB6022A,GB6044",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,22,1,675,36778,36778,"XC,X2",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,2,1,675,36798,36798,"XC,X2",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,7,1,675,36890,36890,X1,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,675,25142,25142,SPD5630,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,5,1,675,36893,36893,"GB6001,GB6022,GB6022A",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,11,1,675,36894,36894,"X2,XC",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,8,1,675,3262,3262,"(X1,X2,X3,XC)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,675,36884,36884,PS5573,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,14,1,675,36771,36771,"PS5202,PS5207,PS5212,PS5217 PS5222,PS5227,PS5232,PS5237, PS5245,PS5250,PS5255,PS5260, PS5265,PS5309",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,2,1,675,36772,36772,"PS5317,PS5326",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,6,1,675,36777,36777,SBLK5103,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,3,1,730,36887,36887,"TAS5619,TAS5622,TAS5624",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,735,36751,36751,TR5164,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,776,776,FU5550,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,748,748,CB5706,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,747,747,CB5568,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,2,1,787,36923,36923,"C5872,C5876",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,4,1,787,3307,3307,"CB5369,CB5375,CB5519,CB5574",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,13,1,787,3308,3308,"CB5408,CB5411,CB5414,CB5417, CB5420,CB5423,CB5426,CB5429, CB5432,CB5435,CB5438,CB5441, CB5454",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,10,1,787,36727,36727,"C5625,C5627,C5629,C5631,C5633, C5635,C5637,C5639,C5641,C5642",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,36728,36728,PMACC5345,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,3,1,787,36733,36733,"CT5103,CT5105,CT5107",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,36734,36734,PM5345,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,5,1,787,752,752,"CB5519A,CB5525,CB5562,CB5566, CB5569",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,3,1,787,36741,36741,"CB5503,CB5507,CB5511",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,7,1,787,777,777,"FU5164,FU5569,FU5562,FU5555, FU5566,FU5573,FU5577, ",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,22,1,787,779,779,"FU5117,FU5123,FU5129,FU5302, FU5202,FU5207,FU5212,FU5217, FU5221,FU5227,FU5232,FU5237, FU5245,FU5250,FU5255,FU5260 FU5265,FU5270,FU5275,FU5309 FU5317,FU5326",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,4,1,787,36742,36742,"FU5135,FU5145,FU5151,FU5157",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,3,1,787,36743,36743,"FU5608,FU5619,FU5622",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,2,1,787,36744,36744,"PS5562,PS5566",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,36745,36745,UPS55056,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,3,1,787,3081,3081,"WLT5608,WLT5611,WLT5614",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,2298,2298,CB5660,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,3072,3072,FBM5710,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,2,1,787,849,849,"FBM5748,FBM5805",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,6,1,787,3076,3076,"(FBM5848(x2),FBM5748(x2), FBM5805(x2))",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,851,851,FBM5848,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,1,1,787,36910,36910,FU5546,0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,13,1,933,36765,36765,"RECP5117,RECP5123,RECP5129, RECP5136,RECP5145,RECP5151, RECP5158,RECP5366,RECP5371, RECP5376,RECP5534,RECP5574, RECP5660B",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,13,1,933,36762,36762,"(RECP5117,RECP5123,RECP5129, RECP5136,RECP5145,RECP5151, RECP5158,RECP5366,RECP5371, RECP5376,RECP5534,RECP5574, RECP5660B)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,8,1,933,36917,36917,"(RECP5117(x2),RECP5123(x2), RECP5129(x2),RECP5534,RECP5574)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,68,1,933,36758,36758,"(RECP5117(x4),RECP5123(x4), RECP5129(x4),RECP5136(x4), RECP5145(x4),RECP5151(x4), RECP5158(x4),RECP5366(x4), RECP5371(x4),RECP5376(x4), RECP5519(x4),RECP5525(x4), RECP5503(x4),RECP5513(x4), RECP5534(x4),RECP5574(x4), RECP5660B(x4))",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,9,1,933,36921,36921,"(RECP5136(x2),RECP5145(x2), RECP5151(x2),RECP5158(x2), RECP5660B)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,7,1,933,36761,36761,"(RECP5366,RECP5371,RECP5376, RECP5503(x2),RECP5513(x2))",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,4,1,933,36767,36767,"RECP5519,RECP5525,RECP5503,RECP5513",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,4,1,933,36766,36766,"(RECP5519,RECP5525,RECP5503, RECP5513)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,4,1,933,36760,36760,"(RECP5519(x2),RECP5525(x2))",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,7,1,933,36759,36759,"(RECP5519(x2),RECP5525(x2), RECP5534,RECP5574,RECP5660B)",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,3,1,1047,36780,36780,"FAN5619,FAN5622,FAN5624",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,2,0,0,3,1,1047,36781,36781,"LS5608,LS5611,LS5614",0,2653,,#ffffff
21380,1,0,0,1,1
```

Comment: Check the value of the `post_max_size` setting in `php.ini`

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was set to 8M. I changed it to 32M and did an iisreset. It is still getting chopped off. Are you thinking the POST may not have all the array to begin with?

Comment: Try using `enctype="multipart/form-data". There may be an issue with sending so much using URL-encoded format.

Comment: Use the Network tab in DevTools to see what's being sent in the POST data.

Comment: It shows that I am passing that last array with all of its contents in the POST